# How to display date only in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I need to display date only in vb.net. These are the steps I went through.

1. added date to sql database. (sql database shows 2013-12-13)
2. created a table to view it. (shows 12/13/2013 12:00:00 AM)

the methods i've used are:

```
<%=Formatdatetime(f_purchasedate,2)%>
<%=FormatDateTime(f_purchasedate, "Short Date")%>
<%Response.Write(FormatDateTime(f_purchasedate, 2))%>
```

Please help. Thanks

EDIT: Was looking at the wrong place. this <%=Formatdatetime(f_purchasedate,2)%> works. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<%=Formatdatetime(f_purchasedate,2)%>
<%=FormatDateTime(f_purchasedate, "Short Date")%>
<%Response.Write(FormatDateTime(f_purchasedate, DateFormat.ShortDate))%>
```

OR

```
 <%Response.Write(f_purchasedate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")))%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f_purchasedate.ToString("d")
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx